# Lucene LongField exact search with Query

Tags: lucene, long-integer

How can I use a TermQuery to exactly match a LongField?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the warning on the [NumericUtils API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html)

**NOTE: This API is for internal purposes only and might change in incompatible ways in the next release.**

I've noticed this becoming a problem for some people, since the NumericUtils API did indeed change significantly from [Version 3.6](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html) to [Version 4.0](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/core/org/apache/lucene/util/NumericUtils.html).  I would recommend avoiding using it directly.

Instead, use a [NumericRangeQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) to search for numeric values.  Precise matches can be obtained by setting maximum and minimum ranges to equal values.

Also, deliberately selecting which fields should be numeric may be helpful.  NumericFields are designed to allow numeric range querying and sorting.  If you don't need to search using it as a numeric value, it probably shouldn't be a NumericField.  Identification numbers, for instance, generally should be keywords, not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
BytesRef ref = new BytesRef();    
NumericUtils.longToPrefixCoded( 12L, 0, ref );
Query q = new TermQuery( new Term( fieldname, ref ) );
```