# How do you index and searchnumbers in Lucene 4.1

Tags: java, search, lucene

In my 3.6 code I was adding numeric field to my index as follows:

```
public void addNumericField(IndexField field, Integer value) {
        addField(field, NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(value));
    }
```

however now you need to pass it a BytesRef argument, and its totally unclear what you are meant to do with the value next so instead I've changed it to (work in progress)

```
public void addNumericField(IndexField field, Integer value) {
        FieldType ft = new FieldType();
        ft.setStored(true);
        ft.setIndexed(true);
        ft.setNumericType(FieldType.NumericType.INT);
        doc.add(new IntField(field.getName(), value, ft));
    }
```

which seemed neater

In 3.6 I also add to override queryparser to make it work for numeric range searches,

```
package org.musicbrainz.search.servlet;

import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.MultiFieldQueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermRangeQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.util.NumericUtils;
import org.musicbrainz.search.LuceneVersion;
import org.musicbrainz.search.index.LabelIndexField;
import org.musicbrainz.search.servlet.mmd1.LabelType;

public class LabelQueryParser extends MultiFieldQueryParser {

    public LabelQueryParser(java.lang.String[] strings, org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer analyzer)
    {
        super(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_VERSION, strings, analyzer);
    }

     protected Query newTermQuery(Term term) {

        if(
                (term.field() == LabelIndexField.CODE.getName())
                ){
            try {
                int number = Integer.parseInt(term.text());
                TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term(term.field(), NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(number)));
                return tq;
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                //If not provided numeric argument just leave as is, 
                //won't give matches
                return super.newTermQuery(term);
            }
        } else {
            return super.newTermQuery(term);

        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * Convert Numeric Fields
     *
     * @param field
     * @param part1
     * @param part2
     * @param inclusive
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Query newRangeQuery(String field,
                               String part1,
                               String part2,
                               boolean inclusive) {

        if (
                (field.equals(LabelIndexField.CODE.getName()))
            )
        {
            part1 = NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(part1));
            part2 = NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(part2));
        }
        TermRangeQuery query = (TermRangeQuery)
                super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2,inclusive);
        return query;
    }

}
```

So I took all this out figuring I didnt need it anymore, but unfortunately no queries on this IntField are now working.

Reading further it seems Intfields are only used for range queries so I don't know how you are meant to just do match queries, and whether the NumericRangeQuery is comptable with the classic Query Parser which I am using.

So I then went back to trying to add my numeric values as encoded string

```
public void addNumericField(IndexField field, Integer value) {

    FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
    fieldType.setStored(true);
    fieldType.setIndexed(true);
    BytesRef bytes = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
    NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(value, 0, bytes);
    doc.add(new Field(field.getName(),bytes, fieldType));
}
```

But at runtime I'm now getting error !

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fields with BytesRef values cannot be indexed
```

But I need to index field, so please how can I index numeric fields like I do in 3.6 so I can search them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the appropriate field. For example `IntField`, `LongField`, etc.

See for example http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntField.html

For querying these fields, see [Lucene LongField exact search with Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158512/lucene-longfield-exact-search-with-query)

Comment: But if using IntField how do I extend QueryParser to search such fields ?

Comment: Return the appropriate NumericRangeQuery in the value parses to an Integer. So, instead of returning a TermQuery, return a NumericRangeQuery in the newTermQuery method, if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up, on how to do it using lucene 4.7:

When indexing I just do as folows:

```
document.add(new IntField("int_field", int_value, Field.Store.YES));
```

And for searching:

```
public class MyQueryParser extends QueryParser {

public MyQueryParser(Version matchVersion, String field, Analyzer anlayzer) {
    super(matchVersion, field, anlayzer);
}

@Override
protected Query getRangeQuery(String field, String part1, String part2, boolean startInclusive, boolean endInclusive) throws ParseException {
    if ("int_field".equals(field)) {
        return NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(field, Integer.parseInt(part1), Integer.parseInt(part2), startInclusive, endInclusive);
    } else {
        return super.getRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive);
    }
}

@Override
protected Query newTermQuery(Term term)
{
    if ("int_field".equals(term.field())) {
        try {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(term.text());
            BytesRef bytes = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
            NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(number, 0, bytes);
            TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term(term.field(), bytes.utf8ToString()));
            return tq;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            //If not provided numeric argument just leave as is, won't give matches
            return super.newTermQuery(term);
        }
    } else {
        return super.newTermQuery(term);
    }
}
```

}

By doing like this, querys like

```
 int_field: 1
 int_field: [1 TO 5]
```

work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

So I have got this working, whether or not this the best way to do things I dont know.

1. Adding number to index as string

   ```
   FieldType fieldType = new FieldType();
   fieldType.setStored(true);
   fieldType.setIndexed(true);
   BytesRef bytes = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
   NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(value, 0, bytes);
   doc.add(new Field(field.getName(),bytes.utf8ToString(), fieldType));
   ```
2. QueryParser, needs to check fieldname using equals(), previously could jut use ==

   ```
   protected Query newTermQuery(Term term)
   {

      if (term.field().equals(LabelIndexField.CODE.getName()))
       {
           try
           {

               int number = Integer.parseInt(term.text());
               BytesRef bytes = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
               NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(number, 0, bytes);
               TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(new Term(term.field(), bytes.utf8ToString()));
               return tq;
           }
           catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
           {
               //If not provided numeric argument just leave as is, won't give matches
               return super.newTermQuery(term);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           return super.newTermQuery(term);

       }
   }
   ```
3. Also the signature of newRangeQuery() has changed, there is extra parameter endInclusive

   ```
   public Query newRangeQuery(String field,
                              String part1,
                              String part2,
                              boolean startInclusive,
                              boolean endInclusive)
   {
       if (
               (field.equals(LabelIndexField.CODE.getName()))
               )
       {
           BytesRef bytes1 = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
           BytesRef bytes2 = new BytesRef(NumericUtils.BUF_SIZE_INT);
           NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(part1), 0, bytes1);
           NumericUtils.intToPrefixCoded(Integer.parseInt(part2), 0, bytes2);
           part1 = bytes1.utf8ToString();
           part2 = bytes2.utf8ToString();
       }
       TermRangeQuery query = (TermRangeQuery)
               super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive);
       return query;

   }
   ```
4. You can get the original intgeral value out of the index as follows

   ```
   NumericUtils.prefixCodedToInt(new BytesRef(code))
   ```